# Using shared memory with matrices

Tags: c, ipc, shared-memory

I want to create a matrix in a shared memory segment. In my second program I can read `tailleX`, `tailleY` but my matrix has just '0' in value. I create my matrix in my function `initialiserSegMem` and values are ok... like always I have some problem with pointers...

my struct mem_share:

```
typedef struct mem_partage{
    int** carte;
    int tailleY;
    int tailleX;
}mem_share;

mem_share initialiserDonneeMem(grille* g){
    mem_share mem_share_carte;
    int x = g->tailleX;
    int y = g->tailleY;
    int i,j;
    mem_share_carte.carte = malloc(y*sizeof(int*));
    for(i=0;i < y;i++){
        mem_share_carte.carte[i] = malloc(x*sizeof(int));
    } 
    mem_share_carte.carte = g->carte;
    mem_share_carte.tailleY = y;
    mem_share_carte.tailleX = x;

    return mem_share_carte;
}

void initialiserSegMem(mem_share *mem_share_carte){
    int shmid,id_memoire,i,j;   
    int test = 100;  

    int *adresse_mem;
    key_t cle;
    cle = 9999;
    /* Creation of the shared memory segment */
    if(shmget(cle,(int) sizeof(mem_share) ,IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0777)== -1) {
        printf("Erreur : Segment de mémoire partagée existant");
    }
    /*on attache le segment a notre espace memoire */
    id_memoire = shmget(cle,0,0);
    adresse_mem = shmat(id_memoire,NULL,0);
    /* les 2premiers int seront les tailles Y et X*/
    printf("tailleY %d zzzz",mem_share_carte->tailleY);
    memcpy(adresse_mem,&mem_share_carte->tailleY,sizeof(int));
    adresse_mem+=sizeof(int);
    memcpy(adresse_mem,&mem_share_carte->tailleX,sizeof(int));
    adresse_mem+=sizeof(int);

    for(i=0;i<mem_share_carte->tailleY;i++){
        printf("\n");
            for(j=0;j<mem_share_carte->tailleX;j++){
                memcpy(adresse_mem,&(mem_share_carte->carte[i][j]),sizeof(int));
            adresse_mem+=sizeof(int);
            }
    }
}
```

In my second program I'm trying to read the shared memories:

```
int shmid,tailleY,tailleX,y,x;

int *adresse_mem;
key_t cle;
/* on recupere la cle du segment */
cle = 9999;
if ((shmid = shmget(cle, 0, 0666)) < 0) {
    perror("shmget");
    exit(1);
    }
/*
    * on attache le segment a notre espace memoire
*/
if ((adresse_mem = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0)) == (char *) -1) {
    perror("shmat");
    exit(1);
}
/*
* on lit le segment :
*  - on recupe la taille y
*  - puis la taille x
*  - puis la carte
*/
memcpy(&tailleY,adresse_mem,sizeof(int));
adresse_mem+=sizeof(int);
printf("tailleY %d",tailleY);
memcpy(&tailleX,adresse_mem,sizeof(int));
printf("tailleX %d",tailleX);
adresse_mem+=sizeof(int);

int** carte;
carte = malloc(tailleY*sizeof(int*));

for(y=0;y<tailleY;y++){
    carte[y] = malloc(tailleX*sizeof(int));
    for(x=0;x>tailleX;x++){
        memcpy(&carte[y][x],adresse_mem,sizeof(int));
        adresse_mem+=sizeof(int);
    }
}
/*
    affichage de la carte
*/
for(y = 0;y<tailleY;y++){
    printf("\n");
    for(x = 0;x<tailleX;x++){
        printf("%d ",carte[y][x]);
    }
}
```

By the way, in my first program I must update my matrix in my shared memories, so can I just call `initialiserSegMem` with my new matrix?

Comment: For starters, don't use "malloc()" :)  Everything - the matrix variable, as well as all matrix contents - must reside in the shared memory you allocate with "shmget()/shmattach()". Excellent link: [Beej's Guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/index.html).

Comment: for(x=0;x>tailleX;x++)

O M G
It was x < taille.......

Answer (score 0):

A simple example code. Child and parent shared a 2D vector using System V shared memory segment. sizeElement is used for offset estimation when the data type change. Here *double* is used. Not Error handling on functions' returned code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <wait.h>

unsigned int sizeof_dm(int rows, int cols, size_t sizeElement){
    size_t size = rows * (sizeof(void *) + (cols * sizeElement));
    return size;
}

void create_index(void **m, int rows, int cols, size_t sizeElement){
    int i;  
    size_t sizeRow = cols * sizeElement;
    m[0] = m+rows;
    for(i=1; i<rows; i++){      
        m[i] = (m[i-1]+sizeRow);
    }
}

void print_matriz(double **matrix, int Rows, int Cols){
    printf("\n");
        for(int i=0; i<Rows; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<Cols; j++)
                printf("%.2f\t",matrix[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    double **matrix;
    int Cols = 10, Rows = 5, shmId;

    size_t sizeMatrix = sizeof_dm(Rows,Cols,sizeof(double));
    shmId = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeMatrix, IPC_CREAT|0600);    
    matrix = shmat(shmId, NULL, 0); 
    create_index((void*)matrix, Rows, Cols, sizeof(double));


    if(fork()){
        int pos=0;
        for(int i=0; i<Rows; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<Cols; j++)
                matrix[i][j] = pos++;
        }       
        wait(NULL); 
        print_matriz(matrix, Rows, Cols); //verify child's write
        shmdt(matrix);
        shmctl(shmId, IPC_RMID, 0);
    }
    else{   
        sleep(3); //avoid race condition
        print_matriz(matrix, Rows, Cols);
        matrix[2][2] = -99.99; //writing test from child
        shmdt(matrix);
    }
    return 0;
}
```